# how to write integer var to file using write() function in c

Tags: c, file, text

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <pthread.h>

void *func(void *ptr);
int file;

int main()
{
  pthread_t thread1, thread2;
  int iret1, iret2;
  int  p;
  p=1;

  file=open("file1.txt", O_CREAT | O_TRUNC | O_RDWR , 0666);
  iret1 = pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, func, (void *)&p);
  pthread_join(thread1, NULL);

  close(file);
  exit(0);
}

void *func(void *ptr)
{
  int *num;
  int i;
  num = (int *)ptr;

  printf("%d ", *num);
  for (i=0; i<10; i++)
  {
    printf("%d", *num);
    write(file, *num, sizeof(*num));
  }
}
```

How to write `integer var` to file using `write()` function in c? 
This is my code. The problem is in the `func()`. If I use `chars` or `const int` it's working fine.

Comment: Please read the manual for `write`.

Comment: `int` or `const int` shouldn't show different results.

Answer (score 2):

**First**, read the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/write) of `write()`. It writes `bytes`, not `element types`.

So, what you are trying to achieve, cannot be accomplished directly with `write()`. you need to use `snprintf()` to convert the `int` to `char` string, which you can use with `write()`. Please check the following code.

**1.** Define a `char` array, `print` the value of the `int` pointer to that array using `snprintf()`.
**2.** Use the `char` array as the argument of `write()`. It'll work.

*NOTE:* It's always a best practice to add some error check to the system calls and library calls. It provides many useful information in the case they fail.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

void *func(void *ptr);
int file;

int main()
{
        pthread_t thread1, thread2;
        int iret1, iret2;
        int  p;
        p=1;

        file=open("file1.txt", O_CREAT | O_TRUNC | O_RDWR , 0666);
        iret1 = pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, func, (void *)&p);
        pthread_join(thread1, NULL);

        close(file);
        exit(0);
}

void *func(void *ptr)
{
        int *num;
        int i, ret = -1;
        num = (int *)ptr;
        char buf[4] = {0};                              //to use with write()

        printf("%d\n", *num);
        for (i=0; i<10; i++)
        {
                printf("%d", *num);
                memset(buf, 0, sizeof (buf));
                snprintf(buf, sizeof *num, "%d", *num);               //print to buffer 
                ret = write(file, buf, strlen(buf));    //write the buf to file
                if (ret < 0)                            //check for erroneous condition
                        printf("ret is %d, errno %d\n", ret, errno);
        }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be snprintf(buf, (sizeof *num + 1), "%d", *num);? snprintf writes atmost size bites including the null termination char. ofcourse then buf should be buf[5]

Answer (score 1):

write(fd, &var, sizeof(i)); is a short fix for this question.

Comment: While this code may solve the question, including an explanation of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person who asked. Consider editing your answer to add explanations and/or give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. See [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).